# Excel Macro Loop Through Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the macro below by clicking a button each time I want to run it. This works ok but is quite time consuming.

In the Summary sheet (range H2:H21) of the workbook I have a list of ID numbers which I have been manually pasting into E3 before running the macro.

Instead of doing this I would like to amend the macro so it loops through all the IDs when I click the button.

The workbook is quite big and takes a while to calculate each time a new ID is pasted in so this needs to be factored in.

Can anyone show me have to do these things?

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    With Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Worksheets.Add()
    .Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("E3").Value
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A22:J63").Copy
    Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A:J").Font.Size = 10
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A22:J27").Copy
    With Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .Font.Size = 10
    End With
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You just have put all that code inside a loop which takes the value of H2:H21 into E3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be optimized, but should get you started.

Check the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

You can put the cursos inside the `Process` procedure, press `F8` key and see what the code does.

**EDIT:** Added `summarySheet.Range("E3").value = cell.value` to the loop

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Process()

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Customize this settings
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx")
    Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set sourceRange = summarySheet.Range("H2:H21")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    ' Loop through each cell in source range
    For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
        ' Validate that cell has a value
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Fill E3 with cell value from range in column H
            summarySheet.Range("E3").value = cell.value

            ' Execute procedure to create new sheet
            CreateNewSheet targetWorkbook, cell.Value, summarySheet
        End If
    Next cell

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub CreateNewSheet(ByVal targetWorkbook As Workbook, ByVal newSheetName As String, ByVal summarySheet As Worksheet)

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    targetSheet.Name = newSheetName

    summarySheet.Range("A22:J63").Copy
    With targetSheet
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Range("A:J").Font.Size = 10
    End With

    summarySheet.Range("A22:J27").Copy
    With targetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thanks for this. It looks good but doesn't seem to input the values in H2:H21 into cell E3 before running.

Comment: It's taking each cell value from the H2 to H21 range to define the sheet's name (that was what I could deduct from your code). if that's not the case, you could add a  `summarySheet.Range("E3").value = cell.value` after this line: `If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then`

Comment: This is great Ricardo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code below should answer your question because it does create the sheets you want.

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim WbBat As Workbook
Dim WsSum As Worksheet
Dim NamesRange As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim TabName As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlManual
End With

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set WbBat = Workbooks("Batsmen.xlsx")
Set WsSum = Wb.Worksheets("Summary")
Set NamesRange = WsSum.Range("H2:H21")

For i = 1 To NamesRange.Cells.Count
    TabName = Trim(NamesRange.Cells(i).Value)
    If Len(TabName) Then                    ' skip if name is blank
        With WbBat.Worksheets.Add()
            .Name = TabName
            WsSum.Range("A22:J63").Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, "A")
            WsSum.Range("A22:J27").Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2)
            .Range("A:J").Columns.AutoFit
            .Range("A1:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Font.Size = 10
        End With
    End If
Next i

With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

Regrettably, it doesn't provide you usable code because it pastes the same data to all sheets. I presume that you have a plan how to vary the data. Unfortunately, I failed to understand such a plan from your question. However, I suspect that you will be able to modify the code to make it useful.